# Smooth curve with no Frenet frame

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth curve. We define a Frenet frame to be an orthonormal frame $X_1, \ldots X_n$ such that for all $1 \leq k \leq n$, $\gamma^{(k)}(t)$ is contained in the linear span of $X_1(t), \ldots, X_k(t)$, $t \in I$.

What is an example of a smooth curve $\gamma$ with no Frenet frame?

Comment: Just for reference, this is an exercise in Unit 2 of Balázs Csikós's "Budapest Semesters in Mathematics" differential geometry notes, page 7 of the following pdf: http://www.cs.elte.hu/geometry/csikos/dif/dif2.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that this can be done with a smooth curve?  Also, I think it might be important to mention that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are smooth vector fields along $\gamma$...

Answer (score 7):

I presume that implicit in the definition is that the frame varies smoothly (as Elliott pointed out).

Here is an example in $\mathbb R^2$:

\begin{equation}
 \gamma(t) = \begin{cases} (\mathrm{e}^{1/t}, 0) &\text{ for $t < 0$} \\\\
(0,0) &\text{ for $t = 0$} \\\\
(0, \mathrm{e}^{-1/t}) &\text{ for $t > 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

---

EDIT:

To give an embedded curve, I will modify the example to work in $\mathbb R^3$. 
\begin{equation}
 \gamma(t) = \begin{cases} (\mathrm{e}^{1/t}, 0, t) &\text{ for $t < 0$} \\\\
(0,0, 0) &\text{ for $t = 0$} \\\\
(0, \mathrm{e}^{-1/t}, t) &\text{ for $t > 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Observe that this curve is embedded with $\dot \gamma \ne 0$.  This means the first vector field in the Frenet frame has to be $\frac{1}{|| \dot \gamma ||} \dot \gamma$.  In particular then, at $t=0$, $X_1 = (1, 0, 0)$.

We've now moved the problem to the second derivative.  For $t < 0$, $\ddot \gamma$ is in the span of $(0, 1, 0)$ and for $t > 0$, $\ddot \gamma$ is in the span of $(0, 0, 1)$.  This means that $X_2$ can't exist.

---

Let me say that we have a partial Frenet frame if we can find such vector fields $X_1, \dots, X_m$, where $m < n$.  If the first $m$ derivatives $\dot \gamma, \ddot \gamma, \dots, \gamma^{(m)}$ are linearly independent, we have the existence of a partial frame by applying Gram-Schmidt.

The way for the Frenet frame to fail to exist is for there to be an $m$ such that at some point, the span of $\{ \dot \gamma, \ddot \gamma, \dots, \gamma^{(m)} \}$ has dimension less than $m$.   In both examples, at the image of $t=0$, the span dropped (for $m=1$ and $m=2$ respectively).  Obviously, this is not a sufficient condition, such we can easily construct examples where things work out.

This construction seems very similar to the one for obtaining a smooth family of matrices without a corresponding smooth frame of eigenvectors.  I don't immediately see how to transform this question to that one.  The question about eigenvectors has [been discussed MO before](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60533/can-always-a-family-of-symmetric-real-matrices-depending-smoothly-on-a-real-param).  (I just provide the link for curiosity's sake, unless someone can explain how to relate these two questions.)

Comment: Argh. I utterly despise this word game of having a smooth curve that is not regular. (Not addressed at @Sam, but at Csikós.) One of those cases where I think the terminology (a curve refers to the parametrisation and not that actual image) actually harms the intuition. (@Sam: +1 for giving the simple answer.)

Comment: Just to elaborate on @Willie's comment: if one looks at the image of this *smooth* curve, one sees that it is the union of the positive $x$-axis and the positive $y$-axis, which is not so smooth!  How does a smooth curve trace out this non-smooth path? Because it uses a bump function to come to a complete stop at $(0,0)$ so that it can then change its direction from one axis to the other.  As Willie wrote: Argh!

Comment: @WillieWong, @MattE : You are absolutely right that this example is taking advantage of the difference between a smooth *map* and an immersed submanifold.  I am updating my answer with what gives a hint at a more general construction.